# Vectorisation in numpy.linalg.tensorsolve

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, linear-algebra, tensor

I am trying to solve the equation:

**Ax** = **B**

for x where **A** and **B** are matrices of shape `(3, 3, 3, 3)` and `(3, 3)`. This can be handled using [`numpy.linalg.tensorsolve()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.tensorsolve.html):

```
numpy.linalg.tensorsolve(A, B, axes=(0, 2))
```

I am now trying to solve this equation in *n* different instances which means my matrices, **A** and **B**, are now shaped `(10, 3, 3, 3, 3)` and `(10, 3, 3)` respectively.

How do I go about using tensorsolve in this case to keep my code vectorised? I don't know what axes to specify or if it is even possible.

Thanks.

Comment: You might need to study the `tensorsolve` code.  I haven't used it, but apparently it's an "inverse" to `tensordot`,  It ravels `B`, and reshapes `A` so it can use `solve(a,b)`,   Alternatively look into using `np.linalg.solve`directly.  You may need to do some sort of transpose on `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You can describe the operation in a functional way with pure Python.

```
list(map(lambda x,y: np.linalg.tensorsolve(x,y), A, B))
```